# Trying to GET a request within electronjs error -202

Tags: javascript, axios, electron

I'm trying to do a HTTPS GET request but keep getting an error in electron js

This comes from the League of legends client lockfile

Any suggestions?

Here's my code.

```
 const axios = require('axios');
    const https = require('https');

  const customHostname = 'localhost';
  const customPort = 59244;
  const username = 'riot';
  const password = 'h1433c5R9ZP0f7Uba8zBWQ';
  const credentials = Buffer.from(`${username}:${password}`).toString('base64');


  const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: `https://${customHostname}:${customPort}`,
    httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  }),
    headers: {
        'Authorization': `Basic ${credentials}`,
      },
  });

  const endpoint = '/lol-summoner/v1/current-summoner';


  axiosInstance.get(endpoint)
  .then((response) => {
    // Handle the response data here
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

I can access this on the browser with no problems

Comment: Localhost would normally be "http://" instead of "https://". Did you enable SSL?

Comment: SSL is disabled via rejectUnauthorized: false?

Comment: You might have to change this line then: 
baseURL: `https://${customHostname}:${customPort}`

Also, if possible can you post your error?

Comment: My bad sorry, might actually help if I posted the actual error:


`[27396:1007/004728.505:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_builtin.cc(701)] CertVerifyProcBuiltin for 127.0.0.1 failed:
----- Certificate i=1 (emailAddress=gametechnologies@riotgames.com,CN=LoL Game Engineering Certificate Authority,OU=LoL Game Engineering,O=Riot Games,L=Santa Monica,ST=California,C=US) -----
ERROR: No matching issuer found


[28404:1007/004728.506:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(968)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202`